# trying to figure out std::count_if

Tags: c++

So I've been stuck with yet another issue and can't figure it out. I'm tryin to write a programm that will count vowels in a txt file. And I'm using different methods to do that. Now I'm stuck with a std::count_if method. Here is the code:

```
std::string vowels = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
    bool findVowel()
    {
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++)
        {
            if (vowels.find(i) != std::string::npos)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void CountIf(std::ifstream& x)
    {
        std::string ww;
        Timer t("count_if/find");
        size_t c = 0;
        while (x >> ww)
        {
            size_t count = std::count_if(ww.begin(), ww.end(), findVowel());
            c = count;
        }
        t.print();
        std::cout << c;
    }
```

and i get the Error: C2064 term doesn't evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments. Maybe I should have used lambda in this case, though I don't think it would have solved the problem.

Hope for some help! Thank you!)

Comment: What are you expecting `findVowel` to do? Right now, I can't make any real sense of what it actually does.

Comment: You need to add a parameter to the `findVowel` function to pass in the string you're testing otherwise you're just looping through the list of vowels and will always return the same result (false as none of the vowels have a value under 12)

Comment: `findVowel` doesn't have any arguments and depends on global state (variable) which in fact should be a constant. So it always return same result. Also `std::count_if` accepts as third argument anything what can be called like a function with single argument and returns boolean value.  Your code passes a boolean value there.

Comment: FYI -- This is much shorter: `const char *vowels = "aeiouyAEIOUY"; ... size_t count = std::count_if(ww.begin(), ww.end(), [&](char c) { return strchr(vowels, c);});` -- No need for a `findVowel` function.

Comment: The immediate issue seems to be *calling* `findVowel()` instead of passing the function pointer to `std::count_if()`. But as pointed out, that will just reveal the logical issues present in the code.

Comment: The third paramete needs to be something you can place `(<some char>)` behind; this must result in an expression convertible to `bool`. A function(pointer) to a function of signature `bool f(char)` could be used or a instance of an object with a call operator with a similar signature `struct FindVowel { bool operator()(char c) const {...} };` `std::count_if(..., FindVowel{});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by checking the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) of `std::count_if`.

As you can see in (3), it requires a *UnaryPredicate*, which is some function (or *function object*) that takes a single parameter and returns true or false. The `count_if` function goes over each char in the input and uses your predicate to check if it counts. Therefore your predicate could look like this:

```
bool isVowel(char c)
{
    static const std::string vowels = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
    return vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}
```

Notice that the function takes a `char` now. When count_if calls your predicate, it passes the current character as an argument. The `for` loop was unnecessary, because `find(c)` iterates over the vowels and returns an index or `npos`. Since the string of vowels is constant and used only in this function, we could make it a `static const`.

When passing your predicate to `count_if`, think of the function as a value.

```
const size_t count = std::count_if(word.begin(), word.end(), isVowel);
```

Notice that there is no `()` after `isVowel`, because we are not calling it, just passing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Now I get it.  You've been a great help!)